# How can i get item from dropdown list as output twice or thrice or any number of times as user inputs

Tags: c#

I am facing problem in retriving output from dropdownlist twice/thrice,etc E.g I made a dropdownlist and items are cat,dog,Mouse.and my design page there is a textbox where we will fetch user input ,dropdownlist as above and 1 submit button.so when user for example typed 2 in textbox and select dog from dopdownlist then ouput should be in 2 times i.e dog,dog and if user inputs 3 then dog,dog,dog,etc.please help me anyone i am trying from so long.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

Create windows forms project. On Form1, add combobox (comboBoxAnimals), textbox (txtTimes) and button (button1). see picture as a ref..

Form1.cs could have a code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBoxAnimals.Items.Add("dog");
            comboBoxAnimals.Items.Add("cat");
            comboBoxAnimals.Items.Add("mouse");
            comboBoxAnimals.SelectedIndex = 1;

            txtTimes.Text = "1";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedAnimal = comboBoxAnimals.SelectedItem.ToString();

            int times = int.Parse(txtTimes.Text);
            var message = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(selectedAnimal, times));
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is not by far perfect example, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks alot vpalmu Sir